# How to create a merged table with FusionTable API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

The Fusiontable API (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#CreatingTables) allows you to create a new **base** table. The description here (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/insert) implies you can specify basetableIds, but using the "Try this API" I have not successfully create a merged table. I have one table with map geometry, which I don't want to duplicate, but want to let users specify their own colors for the geometry.

Has anyone been able to do this? If so, how do you specify the columns to join on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does the base table have the location type columns? If the "map geometry" column/columns have location type set then you may not be able to create a new base table from the existing tableId as there are warnings throughout the docs about using the API to modify or update columns which are two-column locations.

So I think that by "creating" a new table from a base table id which has columns defined as locations you also create new columns and as such wouldn't be able to do this via API.

Try to change the column types to strings and then create the new table. Revert back to location once completed if this is the case?

Hope that helps.

[image: Using the API Docs]

[image]

Comment: The (single) geometry column is indeed typed LOCATION. So that could be the problem. I will try your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem and thought i would post my solution.  It appears that creating merge tables via the API is done by creating views with the sql query endpoint.

[From the Docs](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#createView):

> To create a new merged table, use the following syntax in an HTTP POST
>   request

```
CREATE VIEW <new_table_name> 
AS (SELECT  <column_spec> { <column_spec>}*
FROM <table_list>)
```

So you would generate something like this if you were merging two tables on a 'zipcode' column for example:

```
CREATE VIEW 'My New Table'
AS (
  SELECT  T1.'zipcode', T2.'state', T2.'area', T2.'latitude', T2.'longitude', T2.'geometry'
  FROM somefusiontableid AS T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN someotherfusiontableid AS T2 ON T1.'zipcode' = T2.'zipcode' 
)
```

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this.